# How to prove that $\sum \sin(2\pi n! x)$ does not converge uniformly on $\mathbb Q$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to prove that:

$$\sum_{n \ge 1} \sin(2 \pi n! x)$$

converges absolutely on $\mathbb Q$, but not uniformly.

For absolute convergence, let $x \in \mathbb Q$, then we can write: $x = a/b$ for some $a, b \in \mathbb Z$, $b \neq 0$.

For large enough $n$, $b|k!$, $\forall k \ge n$. Hence, the sequence of partial sums is zero except at a finite amount of places, so it is convergent.

For uniform convergence, I don't know how to approach this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the partial sums of the series by $s_n(x)$ and its sum by $s(x)$. Assume that the convergence is uniform. Then there is an $N$ such that
$$|s_{N-1}(x)-s(x)|<{1\over4},\qquad|s_N(x)-s(x)|<{1\over4}$$
for all $x$, which implies
$$|a_N(x)|=\bigl|\sin(2\pi\> N!\>x)\bigr|<{1\over2}$$
for all $x$. But the latter inequality is violated when $$x:={1\over 4N!}\in{\mathbb Q}\ ,$$ a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x_n = \frac{1}{4n!}$. Then $$\sin\left(2\pi n!x_n\right) = \sin\left(\frac\pi 2\right)=1,$$
so that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{x\in\mathbb Q} \sum_{k=1}^n \sin\left(2\pi k!x\right)=\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}$ and assume there is $N$ such that for every $n>N$ and for every $x\in\mathbb Q$ you have $|f_n(x)-\lim f_n(x)|<\epsilon$.

Now take $x_0=\frac{1}{2p}$, where $p$ is the minimal prime number such that $p>N$. It should be pretty straightforward from here, I think.